# __scrape__ dynamic data behind a chart using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, charts, stockquotes

Is there a way in R which i can extract historical stocks quotes behind a chart based on that historical data from this web site :
https://www.egx.com.eg/en/stocksdata.aspx?ISIN=EGS60322C012

I tried my best with figure out the headers and query from the network tab in chrome broweser with no luck!
Thanks in advance!

I also tired this code for reference

```
rl <- "https://www.egx.com.eg/content/charts/dcp_401410da-0-4.swf?guid=339b28e6-3e74-4477-badb-b49c52a851a5"
r <- GET(url = rl, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"))
headers(r)

text <- content(r, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
text

dput(text,"test.txt")
data <- fromJSON(text)
data
```

[image: the chart is down below the table]

Comment: That website uses Flash (hence the .swf extension). I don't think you can use this way to extract data from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you suggest a suitable way for this task.